# FreeFileSync 10.3 in Ubuntu 18.04 very slow

Tags: 18.04

Is it normal for FreeFileSync to take over 3 hours to sync 1.7GB of data? In Windows it took less than 30sec, but in Ubuntu over 3 hrs?
ps: I'm trying to mirror files from laptop to cell phone, with Windows, it took me less than 30sec to mirror from pc to a tablet. TIA

Comment: This is what I found, in Windows, if I just plug in my cell, it's set by default as media device for file transfer and the apps I used in Windows was SyncBackPro, which won't recognize it, I had to change it to USB storage, as USB storage in Ubuntu the time dropped down from 3hrs to 3min, a lot more than Windows, is there any fine tuning that I can do to get the time close to Windows?

Comment: How do you connect your phone to PC? Are you using SMB/CIFS, FTP, SSHfs?

Comment: I'm using USB cable, but when connected, the phone offers these options: charge only, photo transfer, file transfer, USB, the default is file.